# Properties of a function $C_\ell(\ell)$ which checks an inequality in ideal case (decreasing assumption) and after estimating impact in general case

Tags: real-analysis, st.statistics, inequalities, legendre-polynomials, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose that
$X=2 \ell+1, Y=C_{\ell}$, both $X$ and $Y$ are function of $\ell$, $X$ is increasing and $Y$ is assuming to be decreasing.

But in reality, my data follow a $C_\ell$ increasing for a small part of range ($\ell = [10,40]$) and decreasing after up to $\ell=3000$, so it is difficult to estimate the impact of this short increasing behavior compared to all the other and large decreasing behavior. Here the real behavior of $C_\ell$ :

[image: Real behavior of C_l]

1. I would like to know **under which conditions ( characteristics of $C_\ell$ decreasing ?, properties of $C_\ell$ function ?, conditions on $\ell_{min}$ and $\ell_{max}$ ?) the below inequality is true :**

$$\sigma_{0,2}^{2} - \sigma_{0,1}^{2} = \frac{2\sum_{}^{}(2l + 1)}{({\sum_{}^{}{(2l + 1)C_{l})}}^{2}} \frac{1}{{(f}_{\text{sky}}N_{p}^{2})} - \frac{\sum_{}^{}\frac{2}{(2l + 1)}}{({\sum_{}^{}{C_{l})}}^{2}} \frac{1}{{(f}_{\text{sky}}N_{p}^{2})} = \frac{2}{{(f}_{\text{sky}}N_{p}^{2})}\left\lbrack \frac{\sum_{}^{}(2l + 1)}{({\sum_{}^{}{(2l + 1)C_{l})}}^{2}} - \frac{\sum_{}^{}\frac{1}{(2l + 1)}}{({\sum_{}^{}{C_{l})}}^{2}} \right\rbrack > 0$$

Give that

$\ell \in \lbrack 10,2990\rbrack\quad$ $\text{and}$ $C_{\ell}$ $\in \left\lbrack e^{-9},e^{-7}\right\rbrack$, $\text{$\ell$ is increasing and $C_{l}$ is decreasing}$

Therefore, we only need to check that

$$\frac{\sum_{}^{}(2l + 1)}{({\sum_{}^{}{(2l + 1)C_{l})}}^{2}} - \frac{\sum_{}^{}\frac{1}{(2l + 1)}}{({\sum_{}^{}{C_{l})}}^{2}} > 0$$

Suppose that

$X = 2\ell + 1,Y = C_{\ell}$,both $X$ and $Y$ are function of $\ell$, $X$ is increasing and $Y$ is decreasing.

Then we must show that

$$\frac{\sum_{}^{}(2l + 1)}{({\sum_{}^{}{(2l + 1)C_{l})}}^{2}} - \frac{\sum_{}^{}\frac{1}{(2l + 1)}}{({\sum_{}^{}{C_{l})}}^{2}} = \frac{\sum_{}^{}X}{({\sum_{}^{}{XY)}}^{2}} - \frac{\sum_{}^{}X^{- 1}}{({\sum_{}^{}{Y)}}^{2}} > 0$$

I.E., we need to show that

$$\frac{\sum_{}^{}X}{({\sum_{}^{}{XY)}}^{2}} > \frac{\sum_{}^{}X^{- 1}}{({\sum_{}^{}{Y)}}^{2}} \rightarrow \sum_{}^{}X({\sum_{}^{}{Y)}}^{2} > \sum_{}^{}X^{- 1}({\sum_{}^{}{XY)}}^{2}$$

We then apply Chebyshev`s inequality: since the Chebyshev`s inequality
had different version, we apply one of the classic result stated as the
following theorem (note that this one can be found in the paper link
[enter link description here](https://rgmia.org/papers/v14/v14a94.pdf), and the reference can be
tracked as well):

Theorem:$g:\lbrack a,b\rbrack \rightarrow R$ and p:$\lbrack a,b\rbrack \rightarrow R$ be integrable functions. If $f$ and $g$ are monotonic in the same direction, then

$$\int_{}^{}{p(x)\text{dx}}\int_{}^{}{p(x)f(x)g(x)dx} \geq \int_{}^{}{p(x)f(x)dx}\int_{}^{}{p(x)g(x)dx}$$

In mathematics, we can translate the integrable function to sum
function. Therefore, given P, if F and G are monotonic in the same
direction, i.e., F and G are both increasing or decreasing, then we have
that

$$\sum_{}^{}P\sum_{}^{}{P(FG)} \geq \sum_{}^{}\text{PF}\sum_{}^{}\text{PG}$$

Now let us go back to our prove process:

$$\sum_{}^{}X({\sum_{}^{}{Y)}}^{2} > \sum_{}^{}X^{- 1}({\sum_{}^{}{XY)}}^{2}$$

For the term in parentheses of right side of the inequality, since
$Y$ and $X$ is increasing, we then have that

$${(\sum_{}^{}\text{XY})}^{2} = \sum_{}^{}\text{XY}\sum_{}^{}\text{XY} < \sum_{}^{}Y\sum_{}^{}{X^{2}Y}\ (Here,\ suppose\ P = Y\ and\ F = G = X)$$

Then we have the right side of inequality

$$\sum_{}^{}X^{- 1}({\sum_{}^{}{XY)}}^{2} < \sum_{}^{}X^{- 1}\sum_{}^{}Y\sum_{}^{}{X^{2}Y} = \sum_{}^{}Y(\sum_{}^{}{X^{2}Y}\sum_{}^{}X^{- 1})$$

Then for the term in parentheses of right side of the inequality, we
change it to

$$\sum_{}^{}{X^{2}Y}\sum_{}^{}X^{- 1} = \sum_{}^{}{Y(X^{2})}\sum_{}^{}Y\frac{1}{\text{XY}} = \sum_{}^{}{Y(X^{2})}\sum_{}^{}Y{(XY)}^{- 1}$$

Since $X^{2}$ and $(XY)^{-1}$ are both
increasing, then we have that

$$\sum_{}^{}{X^{2}Y}\sum_{}^{}X^{- 1} = \sum_{}^{}{Y(X^{2})}\sum_{}^{}Y{(XY)}^{- 1} < \sum_{}^{}Y\sum_{}^{}Y{(X^{2})(XY)}^{- 1} = \sum_{}^{}Y\sum_{}^{}X$$

$$(Here,\ suppose\ P = Y\ and\ F = X^{2}\ and\ G = {(XY)}^{- 1})$$

Therefore, we showed that

$$\sum_{}^{}X^{- 1}({\sum_{}^{}{XY)}}^{2} < \sum_{}^{}Y\left( \sum_{}^{}{X^{2}Y}\sum_{}^{}X^{- 1} \right) < \sum_{}^{}Y\sum_{}^{}Y\sum_{}^{}X = \sum_{}^{}X({\sum_{}^{}{Y)}}^{2}$$

**QUESTION :**

2. If someone could tell me if the demonstration is right or not.
3. If I consider $XY$ decreasing, that means that $Y=C_\ell$ decreases muore than $X=2\ell+1$ increases. Unfortunately, I can't check it from a coding and numerical point of view (if I take for example $C_\ell=(\dfrac{1}{2\ell+1} + \text{factor})$ and see the differences with $\text{factor}$ value (positive or negative to be lower or greater than $X=(2\ell+1)$.

I realize that a stronger decreasing for $C_\ell$ than $\dfrac{1}{2\ell+1}$ function decreasing is not enough.

I have to find properties for $Y=C_\ell$ that checks, with $X=(2\ell+1)$ and $XY$ decreasing :

$$\left\lbrack \frac{\sum_{}^{}(2l + 1)}{({\sum_{}^{}{(2l + 1)C_{l})}}^{2}} - \frac{\sum_{}^{}\frac{1}{(2l + 1)}}{({\sum_{}^{}{C_{l})}}^{2}} \right\rbrack > 0$$

Comment: Is $C$ a specific function, or does $Y = C_\ell$ just indicate explicitly that $Y$ depends on $\ell$?  As things stand, this question seems to me to need much more detail before it can reasonably be answered.

Comment: @LSpice . Yes, $Y = C_\ell$ indicate explicitly that  depends on $\ell$ . From your point of view, which are the characteristics that $Y=C_\ell$ must respect to verify the inequality that I would like to demonstrate ?

Comment: I am downvoting both the editing which invalidated an answer, and the posting of a bounty by a user who has not asked or answered any other questions on this site.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to assume that $Y=C_l$ is decreasing in $l$.

Indeed, if your inequality were true for all such $Y$, then its non-strict version would be true for all constant $Y$, say for $Y=1$ for all $l$. So, we would have
$$
\left(\sum_{\ell=\ell_\text{min}}^{\ell_\text{max}} 1\right)^{2}
\ge 
\sum_{\ell=\ell_\text{min}}^{\ell_\text{max}} X^{-1} \sum_{\ell=\ell_\text{min}}^{\ell_\text{max}} X.
$$
However, by the [inequality between the arithmetic and harmonic means](http://math.northwestern.edu/putnam/main-inequalities-results.pdf), exactly the opposite inequality holds (assuming all the values of $X$ are $>0$):
$$
\left(\sum_{\ell=\ell_\text{min}}^{\ell_\text{max}} 1\right)^{2}
< 
\sum_{\ell=\ell_\text{min}}^{\ell_\text{max}} X^{-1} \sum_{\ell=\ell_\text{min}}^{\ell_\text{max}} X.
$$

Comment: @losifPinelis. Thanks for your quick answer. I have slightly modified my question : I would like to know under which conditions ( $C_\ell$ strictly decreasing ?, properties of $C_\ell$ function ?, conditions on $\ell_{min}$ and $\ell_{max}$ or other conditions ) the inequality $(1)$ is true.

Comment: @stefan : This modification is not at all slight, as it invalidates a valid answer. I suggest you yourself specify all the conditions you have for $C_l$ and then perhaps post the modified question separately.

Comment: @losifPinelis. Your answer is true, there is no problem about this. The thing that I have changed is to go deeper in analysis and eventually be able to get characteristics of this decreasing $C_\ell$ function. As you said, assuming that $C_\ell$ is decreasing is not enough and that's the goal of my modification. Best regards